# How to add entries only to specific table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

In my thesis I have two table of contents. One for the main document and one for the appendices. I made both TOC with the `etoc` package. I added sections from my preamble to my main document's TOC. However, they also show up in the appendices' TOC. How can I manage to add entries only to a specific TOC?

Here is what I have done:

In preamble sections like "declaration of academic integrity, acknowledgements, and abstract" I defined a new entry with:

```
\etoctoccontentsline{section}{Preamble Section}
```

The appendices' toc is defined with:

```
\etocdepthtag.toc{mtappendix}
\etocsettagdepth{mtchapter}{none}
\etocsettagdepth{mtappendix}{subsection}
\tableofcontents
```